# Why can't I create an OData service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf-data-services

My machine has VS 2010 Premium installed and I'm having a bit of trouble with item templates.

I'm wanting to follow along with a simple [MSDN Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728275.aspx) to build an OData service so I can learn about them. It says I need to create an ASP.Net application, which I did. Next it says to add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" item, which I don't have available in my item templates.

Even worse, there is no "WCF Data Service" which is kind of crucial for this exercise. What am I missing? Is there some type of SDK or other download that installs OData/WCF Data Service components and templates?

**Update**
I looked at the install logs for ADO.Net Entity Framework Tools and it appears that it installed all the templates into an old VS 2010 **express* edition folder. I no longer have that installed, is there a tool or a method to remove any traces of express so the installer will deploy files to the premium edition I have installed?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Express?

Comment: Woops, thought I added my version. I'm updating my question but it's Premium.

Comment: If you don't have "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" then your VS setup really has a problem. Have you tried repairing it? I just installed premium recently and I have it.

Comment: I'm trying a repair right now. Thanks for the idea. I'll see if that helps.

Comment: The repair didn't do a thing for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Source**: ADO.Net Entity Framework Tools must have been installed with VS 2010 Express which was installed before Premium. When I uninstalled Express it must have kept ADO.Net EF tools and it's references to Express. This is what I did to fix it:

1. Uninstalled "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools" from Control Panel
2. On the VS 2010 Setup disc, navigated to \WCU\EFTools with the command line
3. Used msiexec: `msiexec /i ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi USING_EXUIH=1` to install by itself (VS 2010 maintenance mode wouldn't install it again after I removed it)

Now I have all the appropriate templates to create OData services :)